# Why the input does not update when i change the model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/waGEU/1/

Trying to add or remove element from a list when they are clicked, but it seems that the correct elements aren't being removed, although initially adding them seems to work.

The javascript

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.tags = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        $scope.book = {tags: []}
        $scope.toggle_tag = function(tag) {
            index = $scope.book.tags.indexOf(tag)
            if (index == -1)
                $scope.book.tags.push(tag)
            else
                $scope.book.tags.splice(tag, 1)
        }
    });
```

The HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="book.tags" ng-list="/ /" />
    <p>{{book.tags}}</p>
    <span class="tag" ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-click="toggle_tag(tag)">{{tag}}</span>
</div>
```

The tags can be clicked to add or remove a tag. I add `ng-model` to the input. But when i click it, the input will not update. How can i make it update.

Comment: @aisensiy, you're using splice incorrectly, first.

Comment: what is ng-list and why you are binding input element to an array ??

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry. I will do well next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a two-way binding solution you could introduce an extra variable

```
<input type="text" ng-model="book.tagInputValue" />
```

and keep it in sync with the `book.tags` array using `$scope.$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('book.tags',
    function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
        scope.book.tagInputValue = newValue.join(' ');
    },
    true
);

$scope.$watch('book.tagInputValue',
    function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
        scope.book.tags = (newValue && newValue.length > 0) ?
            newValue.split(/\s+/) : [];
    }
);
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waGEU/9/

You could put all that together inside your own directive, especially if you plan to have a list of books that will all use such input instance-wise.
See: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#writingdirectivesshortversion

However, updating an input field value like that can cause the carret position to switch to the end sometimes (for example when deleting a tag).

Answer (score 3):

The input is not updated because you don't set/bind its value property.

Change this line

```
<input type="text" ng-model="book.tags" ng-list="/ /" />
```

to something like this

```
<input type="text" value="{{book.tags.join(',')}}" />
```

Also check shaunhusain's answer to fix the splice bug you have.

Updated fiddle with both fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/waGEU/6/

Comment: According to AngularJS docs on ng-list and ng-model, the first way should work as well, though.

Comment: I am pretty sure that ng-list converts from the text representation to an array (from input field -> model) and not the other way around.

Comment: Oh. You're correct, and I misread the docs. [Working fiddle, my version](http://jsfiddle.net/waGEU/8/) (more verbose, but fixes a few problems with JavaScript, and keeps ng-model).

Comment: Yeah this is definitely better than cloning the array every time, is this the "accepted" way to handle watching changes on an array, have it evaluate some expression that will have a different value?

Comment: But i cannot type things to update the book.tags now. I dont mean click type is the only way to add tag. Type should also be supported.

Comment: @shaunhusain: Honestly I don't know why his original code didn't work both ways. It might be that there is a one-way limitation when using the ng-list directive. Or it could just not be implemented or a bug. In other cases binding to arrays works just fine and changes are detected properly.

Comment: @aisensiy: Ah, I see. So you want to have a two-way binding. In this case (since it seems that the ng-list directive won't handle that on it's own) you need to make an extra variable that will store a string representation of the array and keep it in sync with the array. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Splice expects an index not the element to remove

http://jsfiddle.net/waGEU/2/

JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.tags = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        $scope.book = {tags: []}
        $scope.toggle_tag = function(tag) {
            index = $scope.book.tags.indexOf(tag)
            if (index == -1)
                $scope.book.tags.push(tag)
            else
                $scope.book.tags.splice(index, 1)
        }
    });
```

changed

```
                $scope.book.tags.splice(tag, 1)
```

to

```
                $scope.book.tags.splice(index, 1)
```

Regarding the other issue of the binding not updating the input:

http://jsfiddle.net/waGEU/5/

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.tags = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        $scope.book = {tags: [], displayTag:""};
        $scope.toggle_tag = function(tag) {
            index = $scope.book.tags.indexOf(tag)
            if (index == -1)
                $scope.book.tags.push(tag)
            else
                $scope.book.tags.splice(tag, 1)
            $scope.book.displayTag = $scope.book.tags.slice(0);
        }
    });
```

Then bind the input to books.displayTag

I think the issue here is probably similar to something you run into with AS3 Bindings, when changing the underlying elements in the array it's not being seen as a change to the array itself.  Perhaps this is something different if so I'd like further clarification as well.

The code I have above "works" but is definitely not efficient as I'm basically cloning the array every time, see the answer that uses:

```
<input type="text" value="{{book.tags.join(',')}}" />
```

to make the binding update instead.

Comment: I think OP's question was about non-updating input. It should display a list of currently selected tags from $scope.book.tags. Edit: on a second reading, it appears OP squeezed two questions in one.

Comment: this answer is different  he is asking to update input element when he clicks on the tags

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff honestly the question was made of it's title and this text "The tags can be clicked to add or remove a tag. I add ng-model to the input. But when i click it, the input will not update. How can i make it update." the rest was me assuming based on the JSFiddle which was the only thing provided.

Comment: @shaunhusain: Still, what little text there was included *"But when i click it, the input will not update. How can i make it update."* so it's pretty clear (well, okay, somewhat clear) that it's the `input` he/she wants to update.

Comment: yeah honestly I didn't see code I jumped right to the fiddle and saw the problem I saw then came back :) @AntonStrogonoff was correct